# Cascading multi-value parameters violate CONSTRAINED flag when filtering parameter list

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

In our cube, we have hierarchies with `All` as the default member at the top level, so `All` then shows up in the parameter list in a SSRS report.

Since it is redundant to have both `All` and `(select all)` in the parameter list when the parameter is a multi-value parameter, we want to get rid of the option to see `All` in the parameter list. This we've accomplished by setting a filter in the auto-generated dataset for the parameter (ParameterLevel <> 0).

The trouble starts when we introduced cascading parameters.... it seems like when a user selects all of the parameters in the top parameter, the next parameter tries to default to `All` and so hitting the CONSTRAINED error:

```
The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOSET function were violated.
```

Any ideas on how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it wasn't because of the second parameter defaulting to `All`... the error seems to show up when `Unknown` (auto-generated by BIDS) was selected. Not sure why this is causing the STRTOSET error though...